# Normal Random Variable less than Uniform

Tags: probability, random-variables

If X is a normally distributed RV and Y is a uniform RV on a to b, is there a distribution of X given it is less than Y?

Intuitively it would be similar to the density of a truncated RV truncated at b, but with slightly less mass in the region a to b than usual.

Is there a way to express this distribution as a function of Phi functions (standard normals) if it exists?

Cheers
Angus

Answer (score 1):

Given $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2), Y \sim \mathcal{U}(a, b)$ and they are independent, consider the CDF of $X|X < Y$:

$$ \begin{align} F_{X|X<Y}(x) &= \Pr\{X \leq x|X < Y\} \\
&= \frac {\Pr\{X \leq x, X < Y\}} {\Pr\{X < Y\}} \\
&= \frac {\displaystyle \frac {1} {b - a} \int_a^b\Pr\{X \leq x, X < y\}dy} 
{\displaystyle \frac {1} {b - a}  \int_a^b \Pr\{X < y\}dy}  \\
\end{align}$$

Consider the numerator. The split the range of $x$ into $3$ cases:

When $x \leq a$,
$$ \int_a^b\Pr\{X \leq x, X < y\}dy = \int_a^b\Pr\{X \leq x\}dy = (b - a)\Phi\left(\frac {x - \mu} {\sigma}\right)$$

When $x \geq b$,
$$ \int_a^b\Pr\{X \leq x, X < y\}dy = \int_a^b\Pr\{X < y\}dy = \int_a^b \Phi\left(\frac {y - \mu} {\sigma}\right)dy$$

When $a < x < b$,
$$ \begin{align} \int_a^b\Pr\{X \leq x, X < y\}dy &= \int_a^x\Pr\{X < y\}dy + \int_x^b\Pr\{X < x\}dy \\
& = \int_a^x \Phi\left(\frac {y - \mu} {\sigma}\right)dy + (b - x)\Phi\left(\frac {x - \mu} {\sigma}\right) \end{align}$$

So obviously for the case $x \geq b$, we have $F_{X|X<Y}(x) = 1$ (the denominator. And there is not much to simplify for the remaining. You may also try to differentiate and obtain the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** I have not checked the details, but it seems @BGM's Answer 
has a method for an analytic solution to your Problem. (+1)

But in your question, you seemed to be
searching for an intuitive view of what is happening. Below is a histogram for 
a million values of $Z = X|X < Y,$ where $X$ is standard normal and
$Y \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,.5).$ [I chose this particular case because it ought to be easy to plug numbers into analytic answers to see what happens.]

The histogram below suggests that the normal is not sharply truncated, but
perhaps one might say 'gradually nearly-linearly truncated' between 0 and .5.
Green lines indicate the interval $(0,.5).$ The red curve is the standard
normal density for negative values. Of course, the total area under the
histogram approximates 1.

[image]

Skeletal R code, if you want it:

```
m = 10^6;  x = rnorm(m);  y = runif(m, 0,.5)
z = x[x < y];  hist(z, prob=T, br=100, col="skyblue")
```

Comment: Thanks I did something very similar to this and got a solution where in the "green" section the truncated normal is multiplied by  1-cdf of the uniform over that region. Then I found a way to calculate the normalising constant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some R code I wrote to calculate the density. It uses the truncnorm package in R. Plotting this over the hist suggested by BruceET seems to confirm it is correct.

```
dens<-function(x,a,b,mean,sd)
  {
  #first find the normalising cosntant.
  etruncab<-etruncnorm(a=a,b=b,mean=mean,sd=sd)
  normc<-1/(1-(1-ptruncnorm(a,-Inf,b,mean,sd))*punif(etruncab,a,b)) 

  out<-numeric(length=length(x))
  out<- dtruncnorm(x=x,a=-Inf,b=b,mean=mean,sd=sd)*normc
  out[x>a]<-out[x>a]*(1-punif(x[x>a],a,b))

  out
}
```